# Query String and hook_page_alter()

Tags: hooks

Is it possible to read the query string and it's values from the &$page param in the hook_page_alter function?

If not, is it possible at all?

Comment: Drupal runs many queries... Which query string's details are you curious to know? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd need to get it from the `$page` variable, you can get the query string from the `$_SERVER` superglobal at any point in the page execution, and convert it into an array with PHP's [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
function MYMODULE_page_alter(&$page) {
  // Convert the query string to an associative array named $qs
  parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $qs);

  // For the string name=jeff&foo=bar:
  //
  // $qs['name'] = 'jeff';
  // $qs['foo'] = 'bar';
}
```